# How can I copy value from dropdown once I select it to text area as text?

Tags: javascript, text, dropdown, field

How do I copy the value of the department from the dropdown to the text area once I select it?
For example if I select IT department I want it to appear in comment text area like "IT Department:"...comment ...
Sorry I'm newbie for coding and I want to learn how to do it
[image]

Comment: Would you mind showing us your code? While images help to some extent, they are hard to grasp for screen readers and visually impaired contributors. And without code, we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Share your code, it will be easier to try and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do with this [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

```js
const eleId = document.getElementById("dropdown");
const textArea = document.getElementById("text");

eleId.addEventListener("change", function() {
  textArea.innerHTML = this.value;
})
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="IT depart">IT depart</option>
<option value="CS depart">CS Depart</option>
<option value="BBA depart">BBA Depart</option>
</select>

<textarea id="text">
</textarea>
```